# Security concern on Apache AllowOverride All setting

Tags: apache-httpd

We are using `Wordpress` in Production environment. Wordpress has few vulnerabilities associated with `xmlrpc.php` file. Looks like one of the preventive measures it to lock down access to `xmlrpc.php`. This can done using the following

```
<Files xmlrpc.php>
    Order allow,deny
    Deny from all
</Files>
```

I verified access to this file is really getting blocked  using `wget/curl` to download the file.

My concern is for httpd to read `.htaccess`, I need to change the following settings `AllowOverride` to `All` in `httpd.conf` which itself is a concern.

Please suggest what is the better way to handle this .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put the `<Files ...>...</Files>` rule in your apache configuration rather than in `.htaccess`, somewhere in the `<Directory>...</Directory>` or `<Location>...</Location>` definition of your Wordpress install.

This will be faster, too, as without `Allowoverride all`, apache doesn't have to read `.htaccess` for every directory it accesses.